# Spring + Hibernate Lazy Load Error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

I'm having an odd situation where I am getting a lazy loading issue on one of my controllers.  **Note: I am using the OpenSessionInViewInterceptor and am annotating my "service" layer as Transactional.**

I have a couple of different ways to load a Person object, one by its key and one by its SSN.  On my person object I have a collection of roles which I lazily load in.  When I load by the Key, I am able to access the list as expected.  When I load by the SSN, I am unable to access the list.

In my service layer configuration file I have added:

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

Here is my service layer piece which loads the person by Key & SSN (I know this needs to be in a DAO / restructured -- this is inherited code) -- Note neither version in the SSN piece allows the loading -- both are in the same class:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public Person loadPersonByKey(final Person.Key personKey) {
    Assert.notNull(personKey);
    return (Person) getHibernateTemplate().get(Person.class, personKey);
} 

@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public Person findPersonBySsn(final SocialSecurityNumber ssn) {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    //List<Person> results = getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedParam("from core.model.entities.Person as person where ssn = :ssn", "ssn", ssn);

    Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(Person.class);
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("ssn", ssn));
    List<Person> results = crit.list();

    int size = results.size();

    Person returnPerson = ((size != 0) ? (Person) results.get(0) : null);
    return returnPerson;
}
```

The only difference in my controllers is one loads by Key, and one loads by SSN.  Here is the pertinent portion of the stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet springmvc threw exception
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: core.model.entities.Person.memberships, no session or session was closed
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:383)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:375)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.readElementByIndex(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:176)
at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentMap.get(PersistentMap.java:169)
at core.model.entities.Person.getMemberships(Person.java:870)
at core.springmvc.controllers.find.FindController.defaultAction(FindController.java:164)
```

Odd note, if I load the person by key immediately after loading by the SSN, I'm able to read the collection without issue.

Edit:

Here are the logs prior to the stack trace:

```
2011-08-02 13:29:32,415 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils CV#905cde28-e60c-4331 P#75004 - Resetting read-only flag of JDBC Connection [Transaction-aware proxy for target Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address_list=(address=(host=127.0.0.1)(protocol=tcp)(port=11523))(load_balance=yes)(failover=yes))), UserName=USER_NAME, Oracle JDBC driver]]
2011-08-02 13:29:32,415 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl CV#905cde28-e60c-4331 P#75004 - disconnecting session
2011-08-02 13:29:32,415 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager CV#905cde28-e60c-4331 P#75004 - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
2011-08-02 13:29:32,415 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils CV#905cde28-e60c-4331 P#75004 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2011-08-02 13:29:32,415 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager CV#905cde28-e60c-4331 P#75004 - transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
```

Comment: Also if calling Hibernate.initialize(person) I still get the initialization exception -- even if I do that in the service layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show enough of the stacktrace to see where the exception is coming from, but I assume it's in your view layer. That's what the open session in view pattern is about. You say you're using the OpenSessionInViewInterceptor, but apparently you're not giving it a wide enough scope. The interceptor applies to method calls. I'm going to guess that you've applied it to your "services". If so, you might as well just turn it off. It's not doing anything for you at all. The whole point of the pattern is to ensure the Session stays open *beyond* the service layer boundary. For a typical webapp, the [OpenSessionInViewFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html) is the appropriate choice.

Comment: Added next two lines of stack trace.  It definitely is not happening inside of the view.

Comment: @Scott: Group controllers into "view". Where is your OpenSessionInViewInterceptor applied?

Comment: Using the standard OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.  It is applied to all requests which are handled via the Dispatcher Servlet.  When I debug through working controllers & non-working controllers I see that there is a session which the Interceptor is utilizing.  Something must be misconfigured though, as the Persistent Collections which Hibernate wraps around my lazily loaded collections show no session when debugging.

Comment: You don't happen to have some code somewhere that's closing or clearing sessions or evicting objects from sessions?

Comment: Had to double check this morning when I got in.  There are no explicit calls to evict, close, clear or the like which I see.

Comment: The only things I can recommend from here are either post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) or do some debugging with a breakpoint on the line in SessionImpl that's outputting the "disconnecting session" line. If that's your session, then it shouldn't be getting disconnected before you try to lazy-load something.